# Intercept Secure URLs on Client Side

Tags: jquery, ajax, playframework, security

I implemented a nice popup modal login dialog for my main page. When I click on the link I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#loginButton').click(function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@{Secure.login()}",
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#myModal").html(data + '<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>');
                    $('#myModal').reveal();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

My application is designed that some controllers need authentication from the user and is redirected before to the login view.

What I want to do is that if the user is accessing a secure controller he needs to see the login popup screen instead of beeing redirected to the view so that I have the same user experience.

I already got a suggestion from google groups:

> a) It would be nicest to intercept all secure links already on the
>   client side with some JavaScript and show your modal dialog. This is
>   independent from what the secure module provides.

But dont know how to implement this or if there is already a solution for this out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is really from jQuery category, not ajax or playframework or web-security. In case all your secure links start with https://

```js
    $('a[href^="https://"]').click(// function here);
```

in case your links are marked with .secure class:

```js
    $('a.secure').click(// function here);
```

the function will show popup modal login dialog, return false and redirect user to the original link url in the end of success callback.